# Cloudformation Rocky Linux firewalld

Tags: aws-cloudformation, firewalld

My usecase. Cloudformation script to spin up ec2 with Rocky Linux 8, Tomcat 9 and webapp.

RL8 uses Firewalld for firewall settings.

Below is my snippet from the CFN script.

```
"echo Unmasking firewalld\n",
"sudo systemctl unmask firewalld\n",

"echo Enabling firewalld\n",
"sudo systemctl enable firewalld\n",

"echo Allow inbound and outbound traffic on port 80\n",
"sudo firewall-offline-cmd --add-port=80/tcp\n",

"echo Allow inbound and outbound traffic on port 443\n", 
"sudo firewall-offline-cmd --add-port=443/tcp\n",

"echo Allow loopback traffic\n",
"sudo firewall-offline-cmd --add-interface=lo\n",

"echo Allow established connections\n",
"sudo firewall-offline-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family=\"ipv4\" source address=\"127.0.0.0/8\" accept'\n",
"sudo firewall-offline-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family=\"ipv4\" source address=\"0.0.0.0/0\" port port=\"443\" protocol=\"tcp\" accept'\n",
"sudo firewall-offline-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family=\"ipv4\" source address=\"0.0.0.0/0\" port port=\"80\" protocol=\"tcp\" accept'\n",
"sudo firewall-offline-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family=\"ipv4\" source address=\"0.0.0.0/0\" port port=\"52311\" protocol=\"tcp\" accept'\n",
"sudo firewall-offline-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family=\"ipv4\" source address=\"0.0.0.0/0\" port port=\"52311\" protocol=\"udp\" accept'\n",
"sudo firewall-offline-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family=\"ipv4\" source address=\"0.0.0.0/0\" port port=\"22\" protocol=\"tcp\" accept'\n",
"sudo firewall-offline-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family=\"ipv4\" source address=\"0.0.0.0/0\" protocol value=\"icmp\" accept'\n",
"sudo firewall-offline-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family=\"ipv4\" source address=\"0.0.0.0/0\" port port=\"68\" protocol=\"udp\" accept'\n",
"sudo firewall-offline-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family=\"ipv4\" source address=\"0.0.0.0/0\" port port=\"323\" protocol=\"udp\" accept'\n",

"echo Starting firewalld - systemctl start firewalld\n",
"sudo systemctl start firewalld\n",

"echo Add service http - firewall-cmd --zone=internal1 --add-service=http\n", 
"sudo firewall-cmd --zone=internal1 --add-service=http\n",

"echo Add service https - firewall-cmd --zone=internal1 --add-service=https\n", 
"sudo firewall-cmd --zone=internal1 --add-service=https\n",
```

CFN script errors out when the following command hits -

```
"echo Add service http - firewall-cmd --zone=internal1 --add-service=http\n", 
"sudo firewall-cmd --zone=internal1 --add-service=http\n",
```

Here is the error -
Add service http - firewall-cmd --zone=internal1 --add-service=http
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.39:/org/fedoraproject/FirewallD1: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

Any cloudformation and firewall experts in here to brainstorm a solution for this?

I have tried the following in the script -

```
"echo Add service http - firewall-offline-cmd --zone=internal1 --add-service=http\n", 
"sudo firewall-offline-cmd --zone=internal1 --add-service=http\n",
```

but the changes are not applied.

https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewall-offline-cmd.html

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste or fat finger error?

```
--zone=internal1
```

Notice the trailing 1: --zone=internal**1**

Comment: no typo there, it is the zone name 'internal1'